# Why does this code run differently in JSBin on repeated runs?

Tags: javascript

On JSBin, this code returns a different number each time it's run, but it doesn't here as a Stack Snippet:

```js
function prime(num) {
  var primes = [];
  var i = 1;
  
  while (primes.length <= num) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      primes.push(i);
    }
    i++;
  }
  
  function isPrime(i) {
    for (var k = 2; k <= Math.sqrt(i); k++) {
      if (i % k === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
  
  return primes.pop();
  
}

console.log(prime(10001));
```

[Link to JSbin](http://jsbin.com/nohowokure/edit?js,console). What shows in the console if you run it repeatedly on JSBin:

[image]

Comment: It does when I run it through JSbin... strange

Comment: Hmm, that's weird how the code snippet here gives the right answer but not on JSBin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the chrome console, you can see the below warning. Thats why the loop is disconnected randomly at some stage.

> Exiting potential infinite loop at line 6. To disable loop protection:
>   add "// noprotect" to your code

If you add the line `// noprotect` on top of your code as below and run it in JSBin, its giving the right answer all the time.

```
// noprotect
function prime(num) {
  var primes = [];
  var i = 1;

  while (primes.length <= num) {
    if (isPrime(i)) {
      primes.push(i);
    }
    i++;
  }

.....
```

Comment: Yup, first thing I did when I followed the bin link.

Comment: Yeah, it was strange when looking at it first time until looking at the dev console :-)